# "cannot execute binary file "in RedHat using perl

Tags: linux, perl, system

I am new to Linux environment. I run a sample system command. I am getting the error as "cannot execute binary file". I run the same program in windows but i used batch file to execute exe file. I need to do the same program in linux environment.

```
sample code:
use strict;
use warnings;
system("/apps01/try.exe");
```

In this, I need to run the exe file and it should wait till the execution completes.Also i tried,

```
bash-3.2$sudo perl sample.pl 
/apps01/try.exe: /apps01/try.exe: cannot execute binary file.
```

Comment: You need OSX to run windows executable.

Comment: @mpapec Are you trolling? That's not what OSX does. (On a more serious note, [*Wine*](http://www.winehq.org/) can execute some Windows binaries on Linux)

Comment: @amon No, I am not, sarcastic maybe. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to Start an .exe-Application on an Unix-Machine, you need Wine (http://www.winehq.org/). Than should the System-Call work

Comment: Shall i use Wine through system command? I need to do this script in automated way @Piggeldy

Comment: @user3085760, It's really hard to remote control an operating system since they tend to assume they have full control of the machine. You'd want to write a persistent Windows program to which you can communicate (e.g. over TCP/IP), and this Windows program would be the one launching `try.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You're already running the script but **try.exe** is a Windows executable (plus not found on your linux machine).

Try to run something else.. something **executable** if you intend to use that function, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $status = system("vi");
```